# Power BI (DAX) How to Ranking by percentage

Tags: powerbi, dax, percentage, ranking, measure

I have a data set "Test1" with repeat customer with all customer by month.
then I count and calculate to percentage

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gsdP.png)

Count_all_customer = COUNTROWS(Test1)
Count_Repeat_customer = COUNTROWS(FILTER(RELATEDTABLE(Test1),Test1[Repeat]="RR"))

%repeat_customer = ([Count_Repeat_customer]/[Count_all_customer])

Now, I want to Ranking Percent Repeat Customer by Area like this
[excel example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVuWA.png)

when I used RANKX --> Result all ranking is "1"

Please advise how to correct this formula to achieve the desired result

Comment: I'm not sure your count of all customers is right. isn't it DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales'[CustomerID]) ? {A, B, C}?

Comment: Yes , I will count all because I need to know how many time their visit in area.

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate dimension to rank on. Normally, you'd have a Customer dimension, so in that case "Count all customers" is just `COUNTROWS(ALL('DimCustomer'))`

```
Ranking the customers:
Customer Rank = RANKX(
        ALL(DimCustomer),
        [Repeat Percent],DENSE)
```